# Is it ok to have low validation loss from the first epoch?

Tags: neural-networks, python, keras, recommender-system

I'm trying to implement Neural Collaborative Filtering recommender system using Keras, the dataset I'm using is movielens-small. Whatever I do to hyperparameters or network, when training, the training loss(MAE) decreases nicely but validation loss (always starts lower than train loss?) stays in place or slightly rises.

[image]

[image]

In a few examples of implementations of this rec system validation loss looks similar:
https://keras.io/examples/structured_data/collaborative_filtering_movielens/
[image: loss of model from keras.io example]

What I'm asking about is how it is possible and does it make any sense that validation loss gets lower than train loss at epoch 1 and doesn't decrease anymore after that.

Here is a code of my net:

```
# https://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-latest-small.zip

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, Flatten, Input, Dot, Dropout, Dense, BatchNormalization, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow import keras

ratings_df = pd.read_csv('./ml-latest-small/ratings.csv', header=0, names=['user_id', 'movie_id', 'rating', 'timestamp'])

# Changing id of movies to 0...n

fixed_movie_id_list = list(ratings_df["movie_id"])
old_to_new_id_dict = dict()
new_index = 0
for index, movie_id in enumerate(fixed_movie_id_list):
    if old_to_new_id_dict.get(movie_id) == None:
        old_to_new_id_dict[movie_id] = new_index
        fixed_movie_id_list[index] = new_index
        new_index += 1
    else:
        fixed_movie_id_list[index] = old_to_new_id_dict[movie_id]

ratings_df["old_movie_id"] = ratings_df["movie_id"] 
ratings_df["movie_id"] = fixed_movie_id_list


ratings_df["user_id"] = ratings_df["user_id"].apply(lambda x: x-1)

ratings_df = ratings_df.reset_index(drop = True)

ratings_df["rating"] = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1)).fit_transform(ratings_df[["rating"]])

train, test = train_test_split(ratings_df, test_size=0.2, stratify=ratings_df['user_id'], random_state=1)

users_len  = len(ratings_df.user_id.unique())
movies_len  = len(ratings_df.movie_id.unique())

movie_embedding = 50
user_embedding = 50

input_movie = Input(shape=[1], name='input-movie')
input_user = Input(shape=[1], name='input-user')

mf_movie_embedding = Embedding(input_dim = movies_len + 1, output_dim = movie_embedding, name='mf_movie_embedding')(input_movie)
mf_user_embedding = Embedding(input_dim = users_len + 1, output_dim = user_embedding, name='mf_user_embedding')(input_user)

mf_movie_flatten = Flatten(name='mf_movie_flatten')(mf_movie_embedding)
mf_user_flatten = Flatten(name='mf_user_flatten')(mf_user_embedding)

mf_output = Dot(axes=1)([mf_movie_flatten, mf_user_flatten]) 

mlp_movie_embedding = Embedding(input_dim = movies_len + 1, output_dim = movie_embedding, name='mlp_movie_embedding')(input_movie)
mlp_user_embedding = Embedding(input_dim = users_len + 1, output_dim = user_embedding, name='mlp_user_embedding')(input_user)

mlp_movie_flatten = Flatten(name='mlp_movie_flatten')(mlp_movie_embedding)
mlp_user_flatten = Flatten(name='mlp_user_flatten')(mlp_user_embedding)

mlp_concatenate = Concatenate(axis=1)([mlp_movie_flatten, mlp_user_flatten]) 
mlp_concatenate_dropout = Dropout(0.2)(mlp_concatenate)

mlp_dense_1 = Dense(32, activation='relu', name='mlp_dense_1')(mlp_concatenate_dropout)
mlp_batch_norm_1 = BatchNormalization(name='mlp_batch_norm_1')(mlp_dense_1)
mlp_dropout_1 = Dropout(0.2)(mlp_batch_norm_1)
mlp_dense_2 = Dense(16, activation='relu', name='mlp_dense_2')(mlp_dropout_1)
mlp_batch_norm_2 = BatchNormalization(name='mlp_batch_norm_2')(mlp_dense_2)
mlp_dropout_2 = Dropout(0.2)(mlp_batch_norm_2)

mlp_output = Dense(8, activation='relu', name='mlp_output')(mlp_dropout_2)

mf_mlp_concat = Concatenate(axis=1)([mf_output, mlp_output])

output = Dense(1, name='output', activation='relu')(mf_mlp_concat)

NeuCF_model = Model([input_user, input_movie], output)
NeuCF_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='mean_absolute_error')

history = NeuCF_model.fit([train.user_id, train.movie_id], train.rating, 
                          epochs=10, 
                          validation_data=[[test.user_id, test.movie_id], test.rating])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('NeuCF_model MAE loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank You, I'll look into it and try more debugging of my code but my question is about the difference between train loss and val loss and why val_loss is as low as it is from the start and does it make any sense.

Comment: *"always starts lower than train loss?"* Typically a model should perform better on training data (for which it has been trained) than on the validation data. However, the first zero epoch points in your graph relate to a model with zero or minimal training. Which loss is lower for the starting conditions of the model is random.

Answer (score 1):

> the difference between train loss and val loss and why val_loss is as low as it is from the start and does it make any sense.

Yes, it can make sense. Neural networks, if they have a large complexity, can always fit the training data if given enough time to train. That doesn't mean that some meaningful pattern has been learned that works on other data as well.

Your graph is also not different from the typical graphs with curves of training loss and validation loss. (See several here: [How to know if model is overfitting or underfitting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/355774/how-to-know-if-model-is-overfitting-or-underfitting))

Typically you have:

- training loss continuously decreasing with increasing model complexity
- validation loss initially decreasing (due to less underfitting), subsequently increasing (due to more overfitting)

Your curves look the same, but it is just that the overfitting starts right-away (or just after the first step, which does reduce the validation loss slightly) and you have little of the part where the training decreases the bias and underfitting. Your model directly starts to overfit.

A similar early overfitting is in this graph where the validation error starts increasing after the cubic polynomial (3rd point along the x-axis in the graph with mean squared error):

[image: graphical example]

From question [Overfitting, but why is the training deviance dropping?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/552798)

If you believe that your features should allow a simple model that can do the fitting, then you probably need to debug and adapt your model.

The question* that was previously added as duplicate is different, in the body text, and is about the case when even the training loss doesn't decrease. However, the answers given to it are very general and can help you with the troubleshooting of your network.

*[What should I do when my neural network doesn't learn?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352036/)